# Displaying list in a list JSP Page

Tags: spring, list, jsp, frontend, jsp-tags

I am trying to display a list and every object of that list has another list which I have to display, the values are coming but are not being displayed, below is the code I have tried if someone could identify what I am doing wrong, it will be very helpful. I am using Spring MVC but I don't think it has anything to do with this error, any help will be appreciated.

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="FILE_TRACKING_MANAGEMENT")
@NamedQuery(name="FileTrackingManagement.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM FileTrackingManagement f")
{

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="fileTrackingManagement")
    private List<FileNoting> fileNotings;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FileTrackingFile
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="fileTrackingManagement")
    private List<FileTrackingFile>  fileTrackingFiles;

    }
```

My Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping("viewMarkedFiles/list")
    public ModelAndView viewMarkedFiles(Model model)
    {
        List<FileTrackingManagement> markedFileList=  fileService.getList();
        //model.addAttribute("markedFileList", markedFileList);

        return new ModelAndView("viewMarkedFiles", "markedFileList", markedFileList);
    }
```

My JSP Page:

```
<table border="1" bgcolor="black" width="600px">
    <c:forEach items="${markedFileList}" var="markedFileVal">
    <%--                <c:set var="fileNotings" value="${jobs[i.index].jobId}"/> --%>
                        <tr
                            style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;"
                            height="30px">

                            <td><c:out value="${markedFileVal.diarynumber}" />
                            <td><c:out value="${markedFileVal.subject}" />
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <c:forEach items="${markedFileList.fileNotings}" var="filenotings">
                            <c:out value="${filenotings.notingData}" /></c:forEach>
                            </td>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

It throws this exception:

```
45: <%--                        <c:out value="${fileVal.description}" /> --%>
46:                         </td>
47:                         <td>
48:                         <c:forEach items="${markedFileList.fileNotings}" var="filenotings">
49:                         <c:out value="${filenotings.notingData}" /></c:forEach>
50:                         
51:                         


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fileNotings"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)



at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't completely change your question after you have asked it and got an answer. Accept the answer, and then ask another question for your other problem, **after having at least tried to solve it by yourself**. I rollbacked to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:forEach items="${markedFileList}" var="markedFileVal">
```

So, you're iterating oover the list `markedFileList`. Inside the body of the tag, the current element is `markedFileVal`.

Then you do

```
<c:forEach items="${markedFileList.fileNotings}" var="filenotings">
```

So you're ietarting over `markedFileList.fileNotings`. But `markedFileList` is a list. It's not the current element. What you want is

```
<c:forEach items="${markedFileVal.fileNotings}" var="filenoting">
```

Also note that I removed the final `s` from `filenotings`. This variable points to a single filenoting. Not to several ones.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out I have updated my question I saw the blunder I made but my problem wasn't that. I wasn't loading the values from database

Comment: It was that when you asked your question and when I answered it and when two people upvoted my answer. Changing the question makes the answer irrelevant, and shows disrespect for people who took time reading and answering your original question.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I have accepted the answer. Really Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Yes @JBNizet, When I came here, the question was updated with new question, so I was wondering what this answer has to do with the question.

Comment: @NamanGala Sorry, I caught my mistake and didn't know it will be answered that quickly, since I am new here

Answer (score 0):

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="fileTrackingManagement")
    private List fileNotings;

The value of fetchType is Lazy by default, when I changed its value, it worked